# Can't Select Item from UL with RSelenium

Tags: r, selenium, rselenium

```
    localDownload <- paste0(getwd(), "/arquivos")
localDownload <- gsub("/", "\\\\\\", localDownload)
eCaps <- list(
  chromeOptions = 
    list(prefs = list("profile.default_content_settings.popups" = 0L,
                      "download.prompt_for_download" = FALSE,
                      "directory_upgrade" = TRUE,
                      "download.default_directory" = localDownload
    )
    )
)

driver <- rsDriver(extraCapabilities = eCaps, browser = c("chrome"), chromever = "89.0.4389.23")
url <- "https://biblioteca.aneel.gov.br/index.html"
driver$client$navigate(url = url)
webElem <- driver$client$findElements("id", "mainFrame")
driver$client$switchToFrame(webElem[[1]])
xpath <- "/html/body/div[1]/form/div/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/a"
opcao <- driver$client$findElement(using = "xpath", value = xpath)
opcao$clickElement()
xpath <- "/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/div[2]/a"
opcao <- driver$client$findElement(using = "xpath", value = xpath)
opcao$clickElement()
xpath <- "/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/button"
opcao <- driver$client$findElement(using = "xpath", value = xpath)
opcao$clickElement()
xpath<- "/html/body/div[14]/ul/li[15]/label/input"
opcao2 <- opcao$findElement(using = "xpath", value = xpath)
opcao2$clickElement()
```

This is my code and im trying to select this option from UL but it is not possible by clicking the element and then select the correct

website:
https://biblioteca.aneel.gov.br/index.html

[section that im trying to select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8C7XT.jpg)

Comment: The web site doesn't work.

Comment: The website is not reachable. Refer https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/basics.html